# Python3 Windows (7) input device detection

Tags: windows, python-3.x, keyboard, usb, hardware

It seems google results have descended to Bing levels and are hence useless. I'm trying to do something relatively simple, detect whether or not a keyboard and/or mouse is plugged in. In short I work at a school and the kids keep moving (read: stealing) mice and keyboards. Ignoring physical security and everything else I want a simple script that can detect if a keyboard/mouse is present at startup/logon and logoff/shutdown. Once I have that information I can raise whatever alerts or logs I need but how do I just detect the presence of a USB keyboard/mouse?

This needs to be a background process running silently. Any ideas?

Comment: See [Registering for Device Notification](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363432). [`RegisterDeviceNotification`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363431) registers to send `WM_DEVICECHANGE` messages to a `WindowProc` or `SERVICE_CONTROL_DEVICEEVENT` notifications to a service control handler. Device classes: [`GUID_DEVINTERFACE_KEYBOARD`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff545881) & [`GUID_DEVINTERFACE_MOUSE`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff545912).

Comment: Thanks for that, looks like what I'm after but how do  use these classes/events within Python3? I see a lot of answers that link to MSDN and it makes sense but I don't know how to access/make use of these objects.